# pycharm: byte literal contains characters > 255

Tags: python, pycharm

I found this inspection in Pycharm: "`byte literal contains characters > 255`". I tried to google it, but found nothing.

What does it mean? Why is it not OK to use such characters?

Comment: A byte is 8 bits, which allows a maximum value of 255. I guess it means that your byte literal has a value above this limit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using a character that falls outside the normal ASCII range of ordinals 0 -> 255.

Put the following 2 lines at the top of your python files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and the error should go away.

If not, email their support, or go to their [forums](http://forum.jetbrains.com/forum/PyCharm).